# Modal page appears briefly when loading ionic 4 app

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a modal page that appears for a split second when the app loads then goes away.  I want to know how to prevent this.

I'm using a tab page with 3 tabs at the bottom.

```js
  initializeApp() {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
          if (!user) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
            unsubscribe();
            console.log('if !user', user);
          } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs');
            unsubscribe();
            console.log('if user', user);
          }
        });
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

Tab page routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            { path: 'profile', loadChildren: '../../pages/profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule'},
            { path: 'itinerary-feed', loadChildren: '../../pages/itinerary-feed/itinerary-feed.module#ItineraryFeedPageModule' },
            { path: 'messages', loadChildren: '../../pages/messages/messages.module#MessagesPageModule' },
        ]
    }
];
```

The itinerary feed page is where the button exists to open the pop up modal.  That page is also the main page when opening the app.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CreateItineraryPage } from '../modals/create-itinerary/create-itinerary.page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-itinerary-feed',
  templateUrl: './itinerary-feed.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./itinerary-feed.page.scss'],
})
export class ItineraryFeedPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async presentModal(): Promise<void> {
      const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: CreateItineraryPage,
      });
      return await modal.present();
    }
}
```

And lastly, I added the modal to my app.module.ts

```js
import { CreateItineraryPageModule } from './pages/modals/create-itinerary/create-itinerary.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    CreateItineraryPageModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    ReactiveFormsModule],
```

So when I initially open the app it automatically opens the modal page and it goes away after a second.  But the real problem is when I hit the back button on the phone it goes back to the modal.  How do I prevent this?  The modal page is just regular component with nothing in it yet.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CreateItineraryPage } from './create-itinerary.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CreateItineraryPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [CreateItineraryPage]
})
export class CreateItineraryPageModule {}
```

and lastly, i removed the route from app-routing.module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/user/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  // TODO: SWITCH BACK AFTER DEVELOPMENT
  { path: 'settings', loadChildren: './pages/settings/settings.module#SettingsPageModule' },
  { path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: './pages/reset-password/reset-password.module#ResetPasswordPageModule' },
  { path: 'signup', loadChildren: './pages/signup/signup.module#SignupPageModule' },
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
  //{ path: 'create-itinerary', loadChildren: './pages/modals/create-itinerary/create-itinerary.module#CreateItineraryPageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[image: The cross button opens the modal]

Comment: That's a default method that's generated when creating a new ionic app.  It essentially removes the splash screen once the app is loaded

Comment: I see, can you setup a demo?

Comment: What's the preferred way to demo?  I could probably do SKYPE

Comment: Ah, no, I was asking for a demo like in stackblitz, where you put a minimum of the code to show the issue

Comment: Here is link to an starter you can fork and update: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tybvzp

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I gave up on the modal and I'm just using a regular page and that works ok.  I think it's a bug in Ionic 4.  The problem is that you have to import the modal module in app.component.ts.  That causes it to appear when loading the app.